# Spring Context configuration that needs the ServletContext passed to constructor

Tags: java, spring

I'm configuring a bean in a spring webapp context that needs the ServletContext passed into the constructor:

```
WebappTemplateLoader(javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext)
```

Here is my bean definition in the xml configuration file:

```
<bean id="ftlTemplateLoader" class="freemarker.cache.WebappTemplateLoader">
    <constructor-arg>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

What do I put in for the constructor arg so that this bean gets a proper ServletContext?

Edit:

**Turns out the answer is:**

```
<bean id="ftlTemplateLoader" class="freemarker.cache.WebappTemplateLoader">
    <constructor-arg value="#{servletContext}">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
<bean id="ftlTemplateLoader" class="freemarker.cache.WebappTemplateLoader">
    <constructor-arg value="#{servletContext}">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

assuming your XML file is being loaded in the context of a `WebApplicationContext`.

Comment: Almost, the #{servletContext} is not a ref, it is the bean itself.  So, instead of ref, it should be:  <constructor-arg value="#{servletContext}">